# How to fill the addon setting from database in cs cart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I new to cscart. I need to fill the settings from database for my new addon.

I have below code in my addon.xml

```
<settings edition_type="ROOT,ULT:VENDOR">
        <sections>
            <section id="general">
                <items>
                    <item id="general">
                        <type>header</type>
                    </item>
                    <item id="info_feature">
                        <type>info</type>
                        <handler>fn_add_setting_info</handler>
                    </item>

                    <item id="order_status">
                        <type>selectbox</type>
                        <default_value>fn_add_setting_info</default_value>
                    </item>
                </items>
            </section>
        </sections>
    </settings>

 In func.php
function  fn_add_setting_info()
{
 $all_datas=get_feature_description();
       foreach($all_datas as $val){
           $arr_sett[$val['feature_id']]=$val['description'];
       }    
      Registry::get('view')->assign('option_details',@$arr_sett);

     }
```

Here the select box  does not fill  fn_add_setting_info() data. How can I do . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
In func.php

function fn_settings_variants_addons_sharesoft_fancycolor_order_status()
    {
         $all_datas=get_feature_description();
           foreach($all_datas as $val){
               $arr_sett[$val['feature_id']]=$val['description'];
           }    

        return $arr_sett;
    }


 addon.xml

  <item id="order_status">
                        <type>selectbox</type>
                        <default_value>fn_add_setting_info</default_value>
                    </item>
```

This is way for fill the select box value with database values.

Answer (score 0):

Is complicated to be detailed here but you can find [here](https://www.hungryweb.net/cs-cart-addons/auto-add-user-to-group-on-register.html) the solution, please download for free and check the code.

In [Auto Add User To Group on Register](https://www.hungryweb.net/cs-cart-addons/auto-add-user-to-group-on-register.html) free CS-Cart add-on on settings are displayed the user groups but you can use if for your own purpose ;)

Keep on smiling

Answer (score 0):

In func.php

```
function fn_settings_variants_addons_sharesoft_fancycolor_order_status()
    {
         $all_datas=get_feature_description();
           foreach($all_datas as $val){
               $arr_sett[$val['feature_id']]=$val['description'];
           }    

        return $arr_sett;
    }
```

addon.xml

```
<item id="order_status">
      <type>selectbox</type>
      <variants/>   <!-- This tag will automatically load values from fn_settings_variants_addons_sharesoft_fancycolor_order_status() function. the function name template is fn_settings_variants_addons_<addon_id>_<setting_id> -->
  </item>
```